# What's the best way to get this design layout using flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AWEr.png)

What's the best way or approach to use to get this kind of layout in flutter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using Chip and Wrap widgets:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Chip"),
      ),
      body: Wrap(
        children: [
          Chip(
            label: Text("test"),
          ),
          Chip(
            label: Text("test"),
          ),
          Chip(
            label: Text("test"),
          ),
          Chip(
            label: Text("test"),
          ),
          Chip(
            label: Text("test"),
          ),
          Chip(
            label: Text("test"),
          ),
          Chip(
            label: Text("test"),
          ),
          Chip(
            label: Text("test"),
          ),
          Chip(
            label: Text("test"),
          ),
        ]
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: if worked, please mark as answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [filter_list](https://pub.dev/packages/filter_list) package to filter your data and achieve the designs you want

sample result:
[image: filter dialog]